# Hibernate map list of enums without jointable

Tags: java, hibernate, enums

I would like to map a list of enums in Hibernate in a specific way.

It should be saved as a comma seperated array of strings in a single column, without using a jointable.

Just like the following annotation saves a single enum value as a string in the database:

```
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
```

I would like to use an `ElementCollection`-like annotation to save the enum list or set in a single column in the database of the entity holding the list of enum values.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, with `@ElementCollection` you have to use `@CollectionTable` which is a separate database table used just to store your values (actually preferable in this case).

You can have a simple `String` mapping and a couple of util methods for converting a CSV string to list of enums and vice versa. Something like this

```
private String myCSVValues;
...
public List<MyEnum> getMyEnums() {
    String[] csvs = this.myCSVValues.split(",");
    List<MyEnum> myEnums = new ArrayList<MyEnum>();
    for (String s : csvs) {
        myEnums.add(MyEnum.valueOf(s));
    }
    return myEnums;
}

public void setMyEnums(List<MyEnum> myEnums) {
    this.myCSVValues = org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.join(myEnums, ",");
}
```

Or, you can try with `@Converter` to map a `List<MyEnum>` directly to a varchar column

```
@Converter(autoApply = true)
public class MyEnumConverter implements AttributeConverter<List<MyEnum>, String> {

    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(List<MyEnum> myEnums) {
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public List<MyEnum> convertToEntityAttribute(String dbData) {
        ...
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It seems though that Hibernate Nverse is not compatible with AttributeConverters (https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-9042) So it will complain that it can not determine the type of the list of enums.

Comment: Yes, looks like you are right about Envers. However, in the bug comments a workaround is mentioned by using a [custom type](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/types.html#types-custom), should be easy to test. And you can always fallback to my first suggestion if it works for you.

Comment: Is the hibernate type a replacement for my attributeconverter? Should I use UserType or CustomCollectionType? (because it's a list) Converter seems much more straightforward, should I put conversion logic in the nullSafeGet() of a custom Type?

Comment: I've never used custom types myself so I can't tell you what will work for sure. I would first try with `UserType` as it looks like it can be done quickly. This is a collection, but of enums and not entities, that's why I think `UserType` could work.